# GSAP TweenMax can null target error fail silently?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm using GSAP in my React app and I've been running into a ton of null target errors when switching back and forth rapidly between routes.

The problem is that my animation takes longer than swiping left / right on my Macbook to go back / forward so, by the time the next page has loaded, the old animation is still running and trying to tween a null target.

I can fix this easily by having a null check in the animation but I have alot of calls to TweenMax so I was wondering if there was an easier way to either 1. fail silently 2. have middleware for null checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how you have things set up, but there's a TweenMax.killTweensOf() that you could use to destroy stuff in your cleanup code when exiting a route. Or shove your tweens into a TimelineLite that you kill(). Or use variables to track your tweens and kill() them when you need to. Lots of options.

If you have GSAP-specific questions, keep in mind that there's a dedicated community at https://greensock.com/forums/

Happy tweening!